# I got rep I didn't deserve. Can I annul it?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I am not sure what happened, but I have a feeling someone appreciated something I did, and decided to give me points. I received 14 upvotes to 14 different questions in 2 minutes. This is obviously not someone who have even read my questions. Can I report this as undeserved rep?

[image]

Comment: Props for the honesty. There is an automated script that will take care of this :)

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I'd like my performance to be clean ;) This feels like doping. ;)

Comment: A Stack Overflow track record will never be fully "clean" though.... You'll earn points for trivial answers to  super easy   questions you feel bad about, and not gain any for  answers you've worked on for two hours. :)

Comment: All that dirty, dirty reputation, @Pekka웃 - eh?

Comment: @Oded https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1998197/239087545/stock-photo-i-t-is-all-mine-senior-gangster-in-shirt-and-suspenders-counting-money-and-looking-at-you-with-239087545.jpg

Comment: 45 of 70 points has now been anulled. But I've kept 25. And good point @Pekka웃 :).